# Swift UIScrollview double tap uitbutton zoom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, uibutton, zooming

I have a view hierarchy like this:

`UIView` -> `UIScrollView` -> `UIView (contentView)` -> `UIButton`

I have added code to the `UIScrollView` to activate zoom when the user double tap.
This is working well, the content view and the `UIButton` are zooming.

In my content view, I have some `UIButton`, my problem is when I double click on this button, I want the scroll view to zoom (this is ok) but I don't want my button to fire the event (this is not ok)

I want the button to only fire an event if the user click on it one time, but not with double tap.

In my case, the `UIButton` can be small, and I want the user to get the possibility to double tap on it to zoom, but to fire an action only if it is a one click.

I try to do this with swift

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `UIButton`, use `UIView` or `UIImageView` as button and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it.

And implement the following logic:

```
if the view is double tapped {
    call your zoom function
}
if the view receives single tap {
    then perform your button click function
}
```

Hope it helps :)